# Finding elements and their indices in a list

Tags: haskell

I need to have both the elements of a list satisfying a predicate *and* the indices of these elements. I can achieve this as follows:

```
import           Data.List (findIndices)

list :: [Int]
list = [3,2,4,1,9]

indices = findIndices (>2) list
elems = [list!!i | i <- indices]
-- same as: elems = filter (>2) list
```

Isn't there a package providing a function giving both the elements and their indices in "one shot" ? I'm surprised I don't find this function somewhere. Otherwise, how to do such a function, improving my above code ? I don't believe this code is optimal since it somehow accesses twice to the elements of the list. I took a quick look at the source code of `findIndices` but I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Do not use `!!`, it is computationally very expensive :( (and an anti-pattern as well, not only because of it inefficiency, but since the index can be any integer, it thus can go out of range).

Comment: Avoid `!!` if possible. Wouldn't `unzip $ filter (p . snd) (zip [0 ..] list)` (where `p = (> 2)`) do?

Comment: Furthermore I find the modelling of two lists (one with indices, and one with elements), rather weird, since this type no longer guarantees that the two lists have the same length.

Comment: pairing a list with their indices is `zip xs [0..]` which you can then filter.

Comment: If your predicates are alike `>2`, `>3`, etc. then `n_ind n l =  [n..length l - 1]` then `[ ind!!i | i <- n_ind 3 ind]` Use the `n_ind` function or create a list.

Comment: If you want to avoid `!!` the least then `tails ind !! 3` will get your limited list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make it more efficient – avoid the `!!` access – by filtering a list of (index, element) tuples.

```
let (indices, elems) = unzip [(i, x) | (i, x) <- zip [0..] list, x > 2]
```

Split into an appropriate function:

```
findItems :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [(Int, a)]
findItems predicate = filter (predicate . snd) . zip [0..]
```

```
let (indices, elems) = unzip $ findItems (>2) list
```

There might be a more straightforward way, and I’ll be happy to find out about it :)

Answer (score 6):

I think [Ry's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647242/745903) is just fine. For a more direct, and in particular more generic one, you could use [`lens` tooling](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4):

```
Prelude> import Control.Lens as L
Prelude L> import Control.Arrow as A
Prelude L A> ifoldr (\i x -> if x>2 then (i:)***(x:) else id) ([],[]) [3,2,4,1,9]
([0,2,4],[3,4,9])
```

This can immediately be used also on arrays (where the index extraction is much more useful)

```
Prelude L A> import qualified Data.Vector as V
Prelude L A V> ifoldr (\i x -> if x>2 then (i:)***(x:) else id) ([],[]) $ V.fromList [3,2,4,1,9]
([0,2,4],[3,4,9])
```

...even on unboxed ones, though these aren't `Foldable`:

```
Prelude L A V> import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
Prelude L A V VU> import Data.Vector.Generic.Lens as V
ifoldrOf vectorTraverse (\i x -> if x>2 then (i:)***(x:) else id) ([],[]) $ VU.fromList [3,2,4,1,9]
([0,2,4],[3.0,4.0,9.0])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(indices, elems) = unzip [ item | item <- zip [0..] ls, (snd item) > 2 ]
```

Not sure that it's any more efficient, but it gets it done in "one shot".