# Explanation of the findIndices function

Tags: haskell

I said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647062/finding-elements-and-their-indices-in-a-list) that I didn't understand the source code of [`findIndices`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#findIndices).

In fact I didn't pay enough attention and I didn't see that there are *two*  definitions of this function:

```
findIndices      :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
#if defined(USE_REPORT_PRELUDE)
findIndices p xs = [ i | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], p x]
#else
-- Efficient definition, adapted from Data.Sequence
{-# INLINE findIndices #-}
findIndices p ls = build $ \c n ->
  let go x r k | p x       = I# k `c` r (k +# 1#)
               | otherwise = r (k +# 1#)
  in foldr go (\_ -> n) ls 0#
#endif  /* USE_REPORT_PRELUDE */
```

I understand the first definition, the one I didn't see. I don't understand the second one. I have a couple of questions:

- what is `if defined(USE_REPORT_PRELUDE)` ?
- can one explain the second definition ? What are `build`, `I#`, `+#`, `1#` ?
- why the second definition is inlined, not the first one ?

Comment: Looks like it's written to take advantage of [`build/foldr` fusion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion#foldr.2Fbuild)

Answer (score 3):

The `CPP` extensions enables the C preprocessor, as for the C programming language. Here, it is used to test if the flag `USE_REPORT_PRELUDE` was set during compilation. According to that flag, the compiler uses the `#if` or the `#else` variant of code.

`build` is a function which could be defined as

```
build f = f (:) []
```

So, using `build (\c n -> ...` essentially lets `c` to the "cons" `(:)`, and `n` to the "nil" `[]`.

This is *not* used for convenience: it is not convenient at all! However, the compiler optimizer works great with `build` and `foldr` combined, so the code is written here in a weird way to take advantage of that.

---

Further, `I# ...` is the low-level constructor for integers. When we normally write

```
x :: Int
x = 4+2
```

GHC implements `x` (very roughly) with a pointer to some memory that reads as `unevaluated: 4+2`. After `x` is forced the first time, this memory gets overwritten with `evaluated: I# 6#`. This is needed to implement laziness.
The "boxing" here refers to the indirection through a pointer.

Instead, the type `Int#` is a plain machine integer, with no pointers, no indirection, no unevaluated expressions. It is strict (instead of lazy), but being more low-level it is more efficient. One creates a value as in

```
x' :: Int#
x' = 6#

x :: Int
x = I# x'
```

Indeed, `Int` is defined as `newtype Int = I# Int#`.

Keep in mind that this is not standard Haskell, but GHC-specific low-level details. In normal code, you should not need to use such unboxed types. In libraries, the authors do that to achieve a little more performance, but that's it.

Sometimes, even if in our code we only use `Int`s, GHC is smart enough to automatically convert our code to using `Int#` and achieve more efficiency, avoiding the boxing. This can be observed if we ask GHC to "dump Core" so that we can see the result of the optimization.

For instance, compiling

```
f :: Int -> Int
f 0 = 0
f n = n + f (n-1)
```

GHC produces a lower level version (this is GHC Core, not Haskell, but it is similar enough to be understood):

```
Main.$wf :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
Main.$wf = \ (ww_s4un :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww_s4un of ds_X210 {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case Main.$wf (GHC.Prim.-# ds_X210 1#) of ww1_s4ur { __DEFAULT ->
        GHC.Prim.+# ds_X210 ww1_s4ur
        };
      0# -> 0#
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice the number of arguments to `go`. `go x r k = ...` === `go x r = \k -> ...`. This is the standard trick to arrange for left-to-right information flow while folding the list (`go` is used as the reducer function, in `foldr go (\_ -> n) ls 0#`). Here, it's the counting of `[0..]`, explicated as the initial `k=0` and the `(k + 1)` on each step (`k` is an unfortunate naming choice, `i` seems better; `k` is overloaded with the irrelevant  "constant" and "continuation", not just "counter" which was probably the intended meaning here).

The [`foldr/build` (sic) fusion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion#foldr.2Fbuild) (linked to by luqui in the comments) turns `foldr c n $ findIndices p [a1,a2,...,an]` into a loop, exposing the inner `foldr` of the `findIndices` definition, avoiding building the actual list structure of the result of the `findIndices` call:

```
build g = g (:) []

foldr c n $ build g = g c n

foldr c n $ findIndices p [a1,a2,...,an] 
== 
foldr c n $ build g where {g c n = ...} 
= 
g c n where {g c n = ...} 
= 
foldr go (const n) [a1,a2,...,an] 0 where {go x r k = ...} 
= 
go a1 (foldr go (const n) [a2,...,an]) 0
=
let { x=a1, r=foldr go (const n) [a2,...,an], k=0 }
in
  if | p x -> c (I# k) (r (k +# 1#))     -- no 'cons' (`:`), only 'c'
     | otherwise ->     r (k +# 1#)     
=
....
```

So you see, it's a standard trick to have `foldr` define a *function* which expects one more *input* argument, to arrange the left-to-right information flow while processing the input list.

All the stuff with the hash sign are "primitive" or "closer-to-machine-level" entities. `I#` is a *primitive `Int`* constructor; `0#` is a machine-level `0`; etc.. This may or may not be exactly correct, but it should be close enough.

---

`foldr/build` fusion seems a particular case of *transducers*-based code transformation, which is based on the fact that nested folds are fused by composing their reducers' transformers (aka transducers), as in

```
foldr c n $
  foldr (tr2 c2) n2 $
    foldr (tr3 c3) n3 xs
=
  foldr (tr2 c) n $         -- fold "replaces" the constructor nodes with its reducer
    foldr (tr3 c3) n3 xs    --   so just use the outer reducer in the first place!
=
    foldr (tr3 (tr2 c)) n xs
=
    foldr ((tr3 . tr2) c) n xs
```

and `build g === foldr . tr` for some appropriate choice of `tr` for a given `g`, so that

```
build g = g c n = (foldr . tr) c n = foldr (tr c) n
```

---

As for `USE_REPORT_PRELUDE`, again, I can't say this with any authority, but I always assumed that it is the compilation flag which is enabled when the mock definitions from the Haskell Report are used as actual code, even though they were intended as an executable specification.